# Validate dates on different formats

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a function that compares different models, one model is from the initial state of the form(the model comes from the backend service, which is a date object), and the other one is when it is converted in the front end.

```js
function getPropertyDifferences(obj1, obj2) {
  return Object.entries(obj1).reduce((diff, [key, value]) => {
    // Check if the property exists in obj2.
    if (obj2.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      const val = obj2[key];

      // Check if obj1's property's value is different from obj2's.
      if (val !== value) {
        return {
          ...diff,
          [key]: val,
        };
      }
    }

    // Otherwise, just return the previous diff object.
    return diff;
  }, {});
}

const a = {
  dateOfBirth: "Wed Jan 06 2021 12:00:05 GMT-0700 (Mexican Pacific Standard Time)",
  name: "test"
};
const b = {
  dateOfBirth: "2021-01-06T12:00:05.357",
  name: "test"
};


console.log(getPropertyDifferences(a, b));
```

As you can see, the dates are the same but in different formats; how can I validate in the function that it is the same?

Comment: Hint: Try creating and comparing date objects with `new Date(stringRepresentation)`

Comment: `dateOfBirth` in `b` is ambiguous since it doesn't have any timezone information in it, so it depends on the location of the user

Comment: at the moment I do not really care about time zone, so I only want to know if 2021-01-06 are equals @Samathingamajig

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steps taken:

- Check if the property is a date using the isNaN() function, which utilizes the valueOf() function of the Date object.
- As you said, you only care about the date without the time; we can use toDateString() extension method of the Date object.

```js
function getPropertyDifferences(obj1, obj2) {
  return Object.entries(obj1).reduce((diff, [key, value]) => {
    // Check if the property exists in obj2.
    if (obj2.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      const val = obj2[key];

      if (typeof val === "string") {
        const obj1Date = new Date(value);
        const obj2Date = new Date(val);

        // check if the values are valid dates. if not, we go through regular comparison
        if (!isNaN(obj1Date) && !isNaN(obj2Date)) {
          return obj1Date.toDateString() !== obj2Date.toDateString() ? { ...diff,
            [key]: val
          } : diff;
        }

      }

      // Check if obj1's property's value is different from obj2's.
      if (val !== value) {
        return {
          ...diff,
          [key]: val,
        };
      }
    }

    // Otherwise, just return the previous diff object.
    return diff;
  }, {});
}

const a = {
  dateOfBirth: "Wed Jan 06 2021 12:00:05 GMT-0700 (Mexican Pacific Standard Time)",
  name: "test",
  num: 1
};
const b = {
  dateOfBirth: "2021-01-06T12:00:05.357",
  name: "test",
  num: 2
};


console.log(getPropertyDifferences(a, b));
```

Comment: It is weird that is working here, but when I try to use in code it throw errors in `const obj1Date = new Date(value);`  Argument of type 'unknown' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | number | Date'., and for `isNaN` says: Argument of type 'Date' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'

Comment: Oh yeah, I suspect it is because your object might have properties of type numbers, and when you pass a number to the Date constructor, it returns a valid Date object. I also recommend creating a new function that encapsulates the date comparison out of this snippet. I just updated the code snippet, try that and see if it works

Answer (score 0):

The ideal option would be `new Date(val) !== new Date(value)`, but since the second time format doesn't include a timezone it is open to interpretation. You also mentioned that you only care about the date itself, not a specific time of day.

```js
function getPropertyDifferences(obj1, obj2) {
  return Object.entries(obj1).reduce((diff, [key, value]) => {
    // Check if the property exists in obj2.
    
    if (obj2.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      const val = obj2[key];

      // Check if obj1's property's value is different from obj2's.
      if (new Date(val.split(" ").slice(2,5).join(" ")) !== new Date(value.split("T")[0])) {
        return {
          ...diff,
          [key]: val,
        };
      }
    }

    // Otherwise, just return the previous diff object.
    return diff;
  }, {});
}

const a = {
  dateOfBirth: "Wed Jan 06 2021 12:00:05 GMT-0700 (Mexican Pacific Standard Time)",
  name: "test"
};
const b = {
  dateOfBirth: "2021-01-06T12:00:05.357",
  name: "test"
};



console.log(getPropertyDifferences(a, b));
```

Comment: But it should no return any, because the values should be the same